# How to make SVG element clickable?

Tags: angularjs, svg

*Angular 1.6*

I want to make the following SVG element clickable:

```
         <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 30.2 34.1" 
            style="enable-background:new 0 0 30.2 34.1;" xml:space="preserve">
            <rect x="19.4" y="0" width="10.8" height="5.4"/>
            <rect x="19.4" y="14.3" width="10.8" height="5.4"/>
            <rect x="19.4" y="28.7" width="10.8" height="5.4"/>
            <rect x="0.2" y="0" width="10.8" height="5.4"/>
            <rect x="0.2" y="14.3" width="10.8" height="5.4"/>
            <rect x="0.2" y="28.7" width="10.8" height="5.4"/>
          </svg>
```

If not Angular it works by simply enclosing it like this `<a href="http://example.com"><svg>...</svg></a>`. But the svg graphics simply dissapears if I do the same in Angular.

Also I tried `<use>` with no success:

```
<svg ...>
<use xlink:href="" ng-attr-xlink:href="{{$ctrl.menu.channels}}" />
...
</svg>
```

How to make my svg element clickable attaching a link to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach was OK, you just need a bit of additional CSS:

```
<a href="#" class="svg">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1">...</svg>
</a>
```

And in your css:

```
a.svg:after {
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution. I don't see my svg icon after enclosing it in `<a>` tag.

Comment: Do you have a plunker or fiddle I can have look at? @trex

Comment: I've tried it in a plunker, it works. I think there is some CSS rule that hides the svg icon in my app.

Comment: Actually, it works even without this extra CSS stuff, I just enclose svg in `<a>`. Now I need to find a rule that hides it :)